# Maximum/Optimal number of Cucumber test scenarios in one file

Tags: cucumber, tdd, bdd, acceptance-testing, cucumber-java

I have a Cucumber feature file with over 66 scenarios! The title of the feature file does represent what the scenarios are all about.

But 66 (200 steps) feels like quite a large number. Does this suggest that my feature title is too broad?

What is the maximum number of scenarios one should have in a single feature file (from a best practice point of view)?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It depends. If you have 2000 feature files with 100000 steps, then it would seem small. You should consider the relative size of the feature file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 200 is an unusually large number of scenarios for a single file. It is likely to be hard to find a particular scenario in the file or to keep it organized. (Multiple smaller files are easier to organize; a directory of files is easier for people to understand and maintain than a long file with comments or worse yet some uncommented ordering scheme.) It will also take a long time to run the file, which will make development difficult.

More importantly, 200 scenarios for a single feature might mean that the feature is extremely complex or that it is very broad. In either case it can probably be broken up into multiple smaller feature files. It also might mean that there are too many scenarios. There might be a scenario for every value of some variable (it might be sufficient to write a single scenario and not worry about different values) or a scenario for every detail of every feature (it might be better to write unit tests, which are smaller and more focused and faster, for details).

But, as with any software metric about the size of a piece of code, there might be a typical size, but every problem is different. Your feature might really be that complex. We can't say without understanding the domain and seeing the feature file.

Answer (score 5):

Although I don't know your system and feature file, I can surely say that there is a misunderstanding of scenarios and their purpose.

The purpose of scenarios is to bring a clarification for the feature by examples. Usually, people tend to write scenarios to cover all use cases. If you do scenarios that way, the feature loses the ability to be human-readable.

Keep in mind that acceptance tests are expensive to write and expensive to change. Write the minimum scenarios. If there is a scenario that doesn't bring any additional value for the understanding of the feature, then that scenario shouldn't be there. Move all use cases into a lower level of testing - unit tests.

In most cases, the feature has the number of scenarios in units, or tens if it's a complex feature.

Edit: If the number of scenarios would go close to 10, I would rather split the feature file into more files describing deeper part of the feature.